# Harmonic Progression with pano

Tags: calculus, harmonic-functions

How would an equation such as this be solved:

[image: http://espice.tech/static/images/chole.jpg]
Any help as to what the answer was, and how it was derived, would be HIGHLY appreciated. Any information about equations such as this would be helpful too.

But, most importantly, what does "pano" mean?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What does $pano$ mean?

Comment: Maybe the limit is the following?

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} \right ]$$

requiring Riemann sums in order to be solved?

Comment: At the OP where did you find the problem?

Comment: Note the difference between these two things: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 {n+1} + \frac 1 {n+2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {pano}$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 {n+1} + \frac 1 {n+2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {\text{pano}}$$  If it was the latter, then maybe "pano" is actually a _word_.  In Portuguese it means "cloth"; in Esperanto it means "bread"; maybe the context would make it clear what it is.  Another guess is it ended with $n_0$, i.e. $n$ with a subscript zero, in which case you'd still need more context to understand what was meant. $\qquad$

Comment: Another guess is that someone copied and pasted something written in mathematical notation and it came out in letters not identical to the symbols that were there before.  I've seen that happen. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

I will probably get downvotes from humorless users for this, but it's too tempting.  Since $pano=(pao)n$, we have

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{pano}\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac{1}{n}\,\sum_{j=1}^{pano-n}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{j}{n}}\\&=\int_0^{pao-1}\,\frac{1}{1+x}\,\text{d}x=\ln(pao)\,.
\end{align}$$

Comment: You're probably right that it was intended as a limit of Riemann sums.  But if I were convinced of that, I'd probably write an explanation of how to view it as a limit of Riemann sums. $\qquad$

Comment: I didn't actually intend to write this answer as an actual answer, but a joke.